# Is it possible to make a query based on the child of a child?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure.
Is it possible to query all the children of `27032017` node where the node `teamLeaderID` of those children is equal to a given value?

[image]

If it's not possible (which seems to be the case for me), should I then move `teamLeaderID` one level up, under `27032017`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to update your query

## REST API

`{{base_url}}/27032017.json?orderBy="teamLeaderID"&equalTo="12daca12tDy8xD1FiXw1"`

**base_url** will be url to your firebase database. you may need to modify [rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart) to access your database.

## Web (JS)

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("27032017");
ref.orderByChild("teamLeaderID").equalTo("12daca12tDy8xD1FiXw1")
   .once("value")
   .then(function (snapshot) {
     console.log(snapshot.key);
});
```

## Android (Java)

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

ref = database.getReference().child("27032017");
refer = ref.orderByChild("teamLeaderID").equalTo("12daca12tDy8xD1FiXw1");

refer.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
           Log.e("Count " ," - "+snapshot);
    }
   @Override
   public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
      Log.e("The read failed: " ,firebaseError.getMessage());
   }
});
```